# createSlice - extraReducers access to slice itself

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I've noticed, that in CreateSlice -> extraReducers, when you use builder to addCase, you can access the slice itself within the addCase method, but nowhere else!

```
const slice = createSlice({
    name: 'sliceName',
    initialState,
    reducers: {...},
    extraReducers: builder => {
        console.log( '1: slice', slice ); // undefined

        builder.addCase( someAsyncThunk.pending, ( state, action ) => {
            console.log( '2: slice', slice ); // full access to slice const - HOW??
        });
    }
});
```

console.output:

```
1: slice undefined
2: slice {name: "sliceName", actions: {…}, caseReducers: {…}, reducer: ƒ}
```

how is that even possible? how can you access slice by its name but only from within the reducer passed to addCase?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the `extraReducers` builder function gets executed *at creation of the slice* (at which point in time the slice does not exist yet), the case reducers themselves are executed when the slice has already been created for a long time. So they can then access the slice.

Comment: sounds about right. could you explain a bit more? or maybe point me to relevant resources?

Comment: This has nothing to do with RTK itself, it is more a thing about JavaScript execution. A variable (the left side of the `=`) does not have a value while value (the right side) is still being calculated. A method call usually means this "calculating" and if there is a callback in there that is called "during calculation", that of course can also not access that variable. But callbacks that are called after creation then can access that value. I really can't explain it much more than that, but you could try reading up on scope and closures.